# Is TeamCity 8.0 compatible with Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-8.0

The TeamCity website reports that the software is compatible and tested with Windows Server 2008 and not on Windows Server 2008 R2 or 2012/R2. **Has anyone deployed TeamCity on Windows Server 2012 R2 ? Is there any known issue that we need to be aware of? Will the customer service team support queries on Windows Server 2012 R2?**

[TeamCity site's System Requirement page](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Supported+Platforms+and+Environments#SupportedPlatformsandEnvironments-Platforms%28OperatingSystems%29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Server 2012 R2 is fully supported.

I have set-up three different build servers on Windows Server 2012 R2. There is no known issues.

I have also used Microsoft SQL Server with TeamCity. (here's a tutorial http://log.ld.si/post/teamcity8-sql-server).

They will support queried ofcourse :)

Comment: Same for me. In addition, I use SQL 2012 in AlwaysOn configuration.